# In Python, how is the in operator implemented to work? Does it use the next() method of the iterators?

Tags: python, in-operator

In Python, it is known that *in* checks for membership in iterators (lists, dictionaries, etc) and looks for substrings in strings. My question is regarding how *in* is implemented to achieve all of the following: 1) test for membership, 2) test for substrings and 3) access to the next element in a for-loop.  For example, when `for i in myList:` or `if i in myList:` is executed, does *in* call `myList.__next__()`? If it does call it, how then does it work with strings, given that *str* objects are not iterators(as checked in Python 2.7) and so do not have the *next()* method? If a detailed discussion of *in*'s implementation is not possible, would appreciate if a gist of it is supplied here.

Comment: Note: the `in` in `for i in x` is not the same operator as the the `in` in `if i in x`.  The first is just syntax/grammar that goes with for, the second is an actual operator.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A class can define how the `in` operator works on instances of that class by defining a `__contains__` method.

The [Python data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) says:

> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`, see [this section in the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).

[Section 6.10.2, "Membership test operations", of the Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) has this to say:

> The operators `in` and `not in` test for membership. `x in s` evaluates to `True` if *x* is a member of *s*, and `False` otherwise. `x not in s` returns the negation of `x in s`. All built-in sequences and set types support this as well as dictionary, for which `in` tests whether the dictionary has a given key. For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.
>
> For the string and bytes types, `x in y` is `True` if and only if *x* is a substring of *y*. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return `True`.
>
> For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, `x in y` returns `True` if `y.__contains__(x)` returns a true value, and `False` otherwise.
>
> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `True` if some value `z` with `x == z` is produced while iterating over `y`. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if `in` raised that exception.
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `True` if and only if there is a non-negative integer index *i* such that `x == y[i]`, and all lower integer indices do not raise `IndexError` exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if `in` raised that exception).
>
> The operator `not in` is defined to have the inverse true value of `in`.

As a comment indicates above, the *expression operator* `in` is distinct from the *keyword* `in` which forms a part of [the `for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for). In the Python grammar, the `in` is "hardcoded" as a part of the syntax of `for`:

> ```
> for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
>               ["else" ":" suite]
> ```

So in the context of a `for` statement, `in` doesn't behave as an operator, it's simply a syntactic marker to separate the `target_list` from the `expression_list`.

Answer (score 6):

Python has `__contains__` special method that is used when you do `item in collection`.

For example, here's a class that "__contains__" all even numbers:

```
>>> class EvenNumbers:
...   def __contains__(self, item):
...     return item % 2 == 0
...
>>> en = EvenNumbers()
>>> 2 in en
True
>>> 3 in en
False
>>>
```