# why does 'in' operator in python acts as comparision operator but when used in for loop it acts as a assognment operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```
'he' in 'hello'
>>>True


for i in 'hello':
  print(i,end = ' ')
>>>'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o'
```

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined.  In the latter case, `in` is not an operator but is rather part of the `for` statement.  It's just two different uses of the same English word.

Comment: it is not assignment, it is iterating over string. Where is the assignment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how is the in operator implemented to work? Does it use the next() method of the iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542860/in-python-how-is-the-in-operator-implemented-to-work-does-it-use-the-next-me)

Answer (score 0):

On the first case `in` is used to check if it is included on second string, while the second `in` is a part of `for` loop for iterating over a string.