# 'in' operator functionality in python

Tags: python, time-complexity

I needed to remove the characters in `string1` which are present in `string2`. Here `string1` and `string2` have only the lower case characters a-z with given condition that the length of `string1` will be greater every time.

I was using the `in` operator:

```
def removeChars (string1, string2):
    for char in string2:
        if char in string1:
            string1 = string1.replace(char, '')
    return string1
```

But I read one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543000/11853363) on Stack Overflow which says:

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

Which means the `in` operator is using a `for` loop behind the scenes.

So my question is, in the `for` loop in my code, should I consider that nested `for` loops are being used, as the `in` operator is using a `for` loop in the background? If yes, what would be the time complexity of this program?

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139660/python-string-in-operator-implementation-algorithm-and-time-complexity) interesting.

Comment: Check this out: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-find-the-time-complexity-of-a-python-code-95b0237e0f2d

Comment: "Which means 'in' operator is using for loop behind the scene." **no it doesn't**. That caveat is merely about the *semantics*. For example, a `dict` or `set` *involves no looping*, rather, it is a hash-based lookup. The point that it is making is that `in` will check for identity first as an optimization *then* equality.

Comment: Are you asking about ``in`` in general or for string specifically?

Comment: In *this particular case*, yes, `in` between strings will involve a linear time algorithm

Comment: Just a small note. You don't have to keep the ```if``` statement in your code. You can simply run ```for char in string2: string1.replace(char,"")```. If the char is there it will be replaced. If not it will simply pass along.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have just given this string problem as an example. My doubt for 'in' operator was in general.

Comment: *More importantly*, the  *semantics* of the `in` operator between two `str` objects, e.g. `s1 in s2`  **is not** equivalent to `any(s1 is e or s1 == e for e in s2)`. `str` objects "sorta" act like containers, but they aren't really.

Comment: @RamShankarKumar That's a tad broad then. The `in` operator can implement [any arbitrary binary operation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__). It doesn't have any specific complexity by itself.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think it is specifically about that quote from the documentation, though.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd prefer not having to guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`in` does not necessarily use loops behind the scenes. For example:

```
r = range(100000000000)
print(333 in r)  # prints True immediately without looping
```

If you were to loop `r` it will take quite a long time, so clearly that doesn't happen.

`in` basically calls (behind the scenes) the object's `__contains__` method. For some iterators it will in fact "loop" through everything but that's not always the case.

This example is basically the same as calling:

```
r.__contains__(333)
```

As pointed out in comments - the `str` objects specifically have a smarter algorithm than just plain loops, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139681/4669778)

Also see example answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964934/what-does-contains-do-what-can-call-contains-function)

And see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

Because the real world scenario would probably mean that `string1` can be arbitrarily long, but the characters to be removed would be a finite and small set, it will probably be much more efficient to just add up all the characters that aren't in `string2`. Something like this:

```
def removeChars (string1, string2):
    result = ''
    for char in string1:
        if char not in string2:
            result += char
    return result
```

This will involve looping over `string1` just once, but multiple checks against `string2` using `in`. This can be further simplified (to avoid `+=` loop over the result):

```
def removeChars (string1, string2):
    return ''.join(char for char in string1 if char not in string2)
```

Comment: Also not for `str` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139660/python-string-in-operator-implementation-algorithm-and-time-complexity). The complexity will be something with `O(n^2)`. `O(n^2m)` in the worst case.

Comment: The question is pretty explicitly talking about strings, so not mentioning this case seems to miss the point.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you are right, I've added some small clarification about strings

Comment: *nnooooo*. This might result in catastrophic quadratic behavior, `result += char` in a loop is going to be quadratic time, although, there is an optimization in the CPython runtime that avoids this, it is not recommended to rely on it, and you should always use a `list` and then `''.join` at the end

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my last example is exactly that

Comment: Sure,  but those two are not the same, algorithmically. The latter is much less efficient than the former

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on another answer, strings already have a method to remove arbitrary many characters at once: ``str.translate``

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It *might* [remain linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487537/why-does-naive-string-concatenation-become-quadratic-above-a-certain-length#comment113882185_44488420) if the OS helps. Ofar: (1) `333 in r` proves nothing, would finish immediately even with iteration. Do sth like `10**99 in range(10**100)` instead. (2) It won't just loop for "some" iterators but likely for most/all. Even `10**99 in iter(range(10**100))` does! (3) The smart string search algo you link to is irrelevant, since we search single characters. Iirc, it isn't even used at all then.

Answer (score 2):

When `in` is equivalent to a loop, it has to 'walk' the iterator and compare each item in turn.

This means each loop is `O(n)`, so for 2 levels this is `O(n²)`

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Note that you actually have 3 loops here - since your `replace` will also walk through the string.

Since replace doens't raise any errors if `char` isn't found, it is simpler to just do this without first testing `char in string1`.

Comment: `in` is not necessarily equivalent to a loop. It depends on the types involved

Comment: Heads up that since this is about removing many characters, using a [translation table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is likely the best complexity at O(n+m).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes - hence my saying "*When* `in` is equivalent to a loop". I was going to write a longer explanation, but that was covered by Ofer above.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a nested for loop, but, it doesn't need to execute completely (on average), only until it reaches a match.

So best case is O(n) -- if all elements of each list match, then for each element of list 1, it takes one step of the inner loop to determine that it matches.

Worst Case is O(n^2) -- if only the very last element of list 2 matches, every iteration of the outer loop will need to test inner loop n times.

At least, that's how I understand it, but, not an expert.

Comment: The average case is "hitting the middle", i.e. O(n/2) == O(n).

Comment: So would that make the average double loop considered O(n*n/2) -> O(n^2)?  (edit: in the example string case. And thanks.)

Comment: Technically O(n m) ("n times m"), where n and m are the size of the two strings.