# How python handle iteration in blank

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

Why python doesn't raise an error when I try do this, instead it print Nothing.

```
empty = []
for i in empty:
    for y in i:
        print(y)
```

Is that python stop iterate it the first level or it just iterates over and print **None**?

I found this when trying to create a infinite loop but it stop when list become empty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542860/in-python-how-is-the-in-operator-implemented-to-work-does-it-use-the-next-me

Comment: It isn't printing anything in the first place. If the array is empty then the for loop won't initialize, since there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: Why do you think it should raise an error?  The standard inifinite loop is such that: `while True:` or `while 1:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to iterate over in `empty` list. Hence, `for` loop won't run even for a single time. However, if it is required to get an error for this you can raise an exception like below:

```
empty = []
if len(empty) == 0:
    raise Exception("List is empty")
for i in empty:
    for y in i:
        print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list variable `empty` is initialized with empty list. so, the first iteration itself will not enter, since the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since the list is empty, the loop will not run at all.